# How to update Custom Fields attached to a project on Workfront?

Tags: java, attask

Currently I am working on AtTask integration with my application. I have a scenario where I need to add some custom_fields with project.

So I start with adding one custom_form with required fields and attached to project while creating project through rest API I am adding these custom_fields value as well. I am able see those custom_fields added with project by hitting get request for given projectID.

```
GET attask/api/project/5587fbca00037fb6b6541ce85f328654?apiKey=xxxx&fields=parameterValues,categoryID
```

Now I have one scenario where I need to update these custom_fields for given projectID by rest API `post request`. So that it will be in sync with my app project and Workfront project's custom fields.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

POST attask/api/project/5587fbca00037fb6b6541ce85f328654?apiKey=xxxx&DE:Custom Field Name1=Custom Field Value1&DE:Custom Field Name2=Custom Field Value2

The Custom Field Names are the names from your custom form.  This assumes that when you created the project (either through AtTask or API calls) that you associated the custom form with the project or task.

In an API call, you need to associate the custom form id as the categoryID.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, However it will not add new custom field. It updates value for existing custom field attached to project.

Comment: I would think that you need to add the custom field when you initially create the custom form.  I don't see anything in the api that allows you to create a new custom field "on the fly."  Perhaps a note is a way to accomplish your goal?